# How to debug Hadoop job, and log intermediate data to console?

Tags: hadoop, println, system.out

I'm trying to write a Hadoop job, and while at first I was trying to create it exnihilo- that's proving too difficult- so my new plan of attack is to bash the word count example into the proper shape.

So, the question now is, how to debug a Hadoop programme?

Apparently it's not possible to do it like this:

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) 
                                  throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  // debugging output
  System.out.println("Hello World! :D");

  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    context.write(word, one);
  }
}
```

There's no way to output intermediate progress of the job onto the console of the namenode while it's executing? Is it the case that I always have to just write the output to a log and then go look it up afterwards?

Comment: Logging stuff has its uses, but really its counters you should be looking at first, both custom and the ones built in. Do yo have a specific problem you're trying to diagnose? This is a large scale, distributed data processing platform, you dont really get console logging.

Comment: I want to iteratively examone the state of variables and make them more and more complex- there's some non trivial operations I need the map reduce job to perform, so I really need something like `console.log`

Comment: Have you tried unit testing your code first then. You can log in a mapper, it will just go in the log file for that mappers instance. Probably best to use a small amount of input data to start with.

Comment: @s.matthew.english Using Log4j, the config might be set at a level higher than INFO. I've had that happen in the past. You can try using `log.warn()`